# On assigning a bigger number directly to a const variable in javascript , the value changes/gets rounded off. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, integer-overflow

I have assigned 90071992547419999992 to a const variable 'a' and I'm trying to console its value. The compiler shows 90071992547420000000 as the answer. Why is the number getting rounded? Can anyone explain how overflow is handled in javascript?

```js
const a = 90071992547419999992;
console.log(a);
console.log(typeof a);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: That number is bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: check out `const a = 90071992547419999992n;` *SO's console doesn't print them right. Either use `console.log(""+a)` or look at the browser console.*

Comment: I do not think JavaScript has integer overflow.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But the above number is not a floating point number right?

Comment: @PrincyAjit yes it is. JS numbers are (in principle) always floating point numbers.

Comment: @PrincyAjit *You didn't read the `typeof` that value*. It's because that is not a number anymore. It's a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: @evolutionxbox technically not, but kind of? Ain't it an integer overflow that happens when you apply a bit-operation to a number that's outside the int32 number space?

Answer (score 0):

One of the comment is right. It is bigger than the **Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER**
which causes Javascript to break. You can do big operations than **Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER** by just adding a **n** at the last of the number or passing the number to BigInt('aabbcc') function, it will return a bigint number. It was introduced in ES2020, so it will not work in older versions.

```
const a = 90071992547419999992n;
console.log(a);
console.log(typeof a);
```

Comment: *"...which causes Javascript to break"* there's nothing broken here. Everything works exactly as intended and defined. It's just not intuitive. *"You can do big operations than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER by just adding a n at the last of the number."* `const a = 90071992547419999.992n` throws a SyntaxError. so does `const a = 90071992547419999992n + 1;`

Comment: @Thomas You need to convert 1 (which is a integer) to a bigint because you are doing operations with bigint. Which means const a = 90071992547419999992n + 1n; will not give any errors.